# Why/When do we need to call an async method from a sync method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous-programming, async

It is my first question here so I hope I'm not doing a mistake. I see a plethora of questions in SO that people ask "how can I call an async method from a sync method?". Given my little background on the subject, I wonder why/when we need to call an async method from a sync method. Isn't to embrace async code always possible?

Comment: Well after you have ensured that certain operation happened in a thread-safe way, what comes after doesn't have to be synced necessarily. Say you want to send a notification after altering a "global" state, the whole sync no need to wait for the notification to be completed. Basically, because it's blocking and making other threads to wait. It's a premise to make synced blocks/operations as atomic as possible to avoid locks

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a synchronous codebase of hundreds of thousands lines of code. In it, you have a synchronous method `DoStuff()`, which calls `GetStuff()` from an external library.

When migrating to a new version of a library, you notice `GetStuff()` was replaced with `GetStuffAsync()`. Now, you could make your `DoStuff()` method asynchronous as well and await the new method, but that's a breaking change - you'd need to refactor all the callers of that method, callers of callers, etc., all the way up to the entry point (which may or may not support an async signature itself) and risk breaking legacy code which does not play well with being executed in an asynchronous way.

Or you could just call `GetStuffAsync()` in a synchronous way, giving up on the advantages of asynchronous execution, but only changing the code in a single place in a way that's compatible with the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain meaning of _but only changing the code in a single place in a way that's compatible with the rest of the codebase_ ?

Comment: instead of  `that's a breaking change - you'd need to refactor all the callers of that method, callers of callers, etc., all the way up to the entry point `  you only change the code doing the call to the async method making it synched. This way no "caller of the caller and so on" needs to be changed

Answer (score 3):

You often end up in a sync method, even if everything else in your app is async.

Either `void Main()`, or `void Button1_Clicked()`, or `HTTPResult Some_Endpoint(Request request)` or somesuch.

Comment: always? what about `void async Task Main()` ?

Comment: @snr that's only existed for 2 years. Projects might not be on the cutting edge even now.

Comment: @snr And even under the hood, the code that calls your `Main` is itself synchronous. It can't be turtles all the way down, unless the `async/await` machinery extended beyond the process and into the kernel